# Changes are not reflected in UI in react

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

When a user like a post, then the count is incremented in ui. Bu when a user remove the like then count ui is not changing though it is changed in server.How to solve it?
When a user like a post, then the count is incremented in ui. Bu when a user remove the like then count ui is not changing though it is changed in server.How to solve it?

```
import React from 'react';
import moment from 'moment';
import CommentForm from './CommentForm';
import CommentList from './CommentList';
import CommentModal from './CommentModal';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { startAddComment, startAddLike, startRemoveLike } from 
'../actions/post';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import UserInfo from './UserInfo';


class PostListItem extends React.Component{
 constructor(props){
     super(props);
     this.state = {
         isliked: false,
         commentM: undefined,
         likes: this.props.likes
     }
 }

 componentDidMount(){
    if(this.props.likes.includes(this.props.user.uid)){
        this.setState(() => ({isliked:true}));
    }
}


onClickedLike = () =>{

   if(this.state.isliked === false){
       this.props.dispatch(startAddLike(this.props._id));
       this.setState(()=>{
           console.log(this.props);
           return{
               isliked:true     
            }
            });
   } else{
       this.props.dispatch(startRemoveLike(this.props._id));
       this.setState(()=>({isliked:false}));
   } 
}

openModal = () =>{
    this.setState({commentM: this.props.comments});
}
closeModal = () =>{
    this.setState(({commentM: undefined}));
}

 render(){
    return(
        <div className="post">
            <div className="post__header">
                <UserInfo user={this.props.author}
                   time={this.props.createdAt}/>

                {
                    (this.props.user.uid === this.props.author.uid)?
                    <Link to={`/edit/${this.props._id}`} 
 className="post__edit">
                    Edit</Link>:''    
                }

                {/* <p className="post__time"> 
 {moment(this.props.createdAt).fromNow()}</p> */}
            </div>
            <div className="post__caption">{this.props.caption}</div>
            <img src={this.props.content} className="post__content"/>
            <div className="post__extra">
                <div className="post__lc">
                    <button className="post__button"
                        onClick={this.onClickedLike}
                    >{this.state.isliked? <i className="fas fa-futbol"></i> 
 : <i className="far fa-futbol"></i>}
                    </button>    
                    <button className="post__button"
                        onClick={this.openModal}><i className="far fa- 
 comment"></i>
                    </button>
                </div>

             {this.props.likes.length !== 0 && <p className="post__like"> 
{this.props.likes.length} {this.props.likes.length === 1? 'like':'likes'} 
</p>}  // likes count is not changing while removing the like(ui only)

                <CommentModal 
                    commentM={this.state.commentM}
                    closeModal={this.closeModal}/>

                <CommentForm onSubmit={(comment) => {
                  this.props.dispatch(startAddComment(this.props._id, 
comment));
                }} />
             {this.props.comments && <CommentList comments= 
{this.props.comments}/>}    
            </div>               
        </div>
    );
}
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
return{
    user: state.auth
}
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PostListItem);
```

Comment: Where is the "likes" coming from? If you are sending the element state to the redux store, why not subscribe to it directly (using mapStateToProps) and avoid creating an internal state for those same properties?

Comment: It is subscribed to redux store in the POSTLIST component. and the POSTLIST is sending props to the above(POSTLISTITEM) component. The UI is changing perfectly when user like a post or comment in the post. But it's not reflecting in the UI when user removes the like though store updates.